# How to add number of months to Date object?

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime

How can I do the following in .NET?

```
Dim d As Date = Today
d = d + [12 months]
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`DateTime.AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) method provided with `DateTime`

> Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of months to the
>   value of this instance.

```
d = d.AddMonths(12)
```

See also:

> This method does not change the value of this DateTime object.
>   Instead, it returns a new DateTime object whose value is the result of
>   this operation.
>
> The AddMonths method calculates the resulting month and year, taking
>   into account leap years and the number of days in a month, then
>   adjusts the day part of the resulting DateTime object. If the
>   resulting day is not a valid day in the resulting month, the last
>   valid day of the resulting month is used. For example, March 31st + 1
>   month = April 30th. The time-of-day part of the resulting DateTime
>   object remains the same as this instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DateTime.AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) method of .NET Framework.

> Returns a new DateTime that **adds the specified number of months to the
>   value of this instance**.

```
Dim d As Date = Today
d = d.AddMonths(12)
```

*Be aware*, since `DateTime` is *[immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)*, this type of methods return new instance of `DateTime` objects. It doesn't change the original value.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you want:

`Dim d As Date = DateTime.Now.Date`

`d = d.AddMonths(12)`

Note that `Date` is actually a `DateTime` type